# How to plot a Cone inside a cylinder?

Tags: plotting

I would like to generate the following plot. Any ideas would be welcome.

[image]

Comment: Like `Graphics3D[{{Cone[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}, 1], Cone[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 2}}, 1]}, {Opacity[2/3], Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}, 1]}}]`?

Answer (score 5):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{Cos[u], Sin[u], 2 v}, {Cos[u] v, Sin[u] v,  2 - v}, 
  {Cos[u] v, Sin[u] v, v}}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> FaceForm[Opacity[.5, Red], Opacity[.5, Yellow]], 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or with `Mesh` lines on the cones:

```
pplt1 = ParametricPlot3D[{{Cos[u] v, Sin[u] v, 2 - v}, 
     {Cos[u] v, Sin[u] v, v}}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 1}, Mesh -> {40, 8}, 
   BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> None, 2 -> None, {1, 2} -> Directive[Thick, Purple]}, 
   PlotStyle -> FaceForm[Opacity[.5, Blue], Opacity[.5, Orange]], 
   Boxed -> False, Axes -> False];
pplt2 = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u], Sin[u], 2 v}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 1}, 
   Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> FaceForm[Opacity[.5, Red], Opacity[.5, Yellow]], 
   Boxed -> False, Axes -> False];
Show[pplt2, pplt1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]